# Timeshift restored snapshot undone after restart

Tags: 20.04, timeshift

When using Timeshift to go back to the working version of my Ubuntu system, the working version only stays until I shut the PC down and turn it back on. When I do so, it goes back to the non-working version.

What can I do to persist the working snapshot's even after shut down?

P.S rebooting doesn't revert back to non-working version, turning off and back on does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how it works with Timeshift, but BTRFS snapshots are only 'restored' temporarily. You need to set the snapshot as your default subvolume.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622334 on how to use the command line to set the default subvolume.

Comment: My snapshot type is RSYNC (in Timeshift settings). Do I still need to do this regardless?

Comment: @Cole, my bad, I thought Timeshift was a GUI to btrfs snapshots. Clearly not. Though it sounds like the snapshot is just stored somewhere as a folder, and the program temporarily mounts those snapshots as the root file system, or remounts part of the snapshot.